# File google-services.json is missing from module root folder. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it

Tags: android, json, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I have a project with 1 module and 2 applications. The module is used for code parts that both applications uses. Of course I have separate google-services.json files in the app's root folders.

The build was working very well last Friday.

Now I try to compile and got this error:

```
File google-services.json is missing from module root folder. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.
:DoToDoSenderApp:compileDebugSources
:DoToDoSenderApp:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Error:Execution failed for task ':DoToDoSenderApp:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

The only informative error message was about this google-services.json file missing in my module root folder.

I don't know what is the problem here?

The module is not an application, why would I have to add a google-services.json file and why it was worked some days ago without modification?

### Edit

I have made a new Google app in Google API console and added a new google-services.json file even to my module, got the same error.

Comment: Could you add a description of the folder structure, showing the project, apps and where the google-services.json files are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add multiDexEnabled true in your project app gradle file and check,

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: tried that but i still get the same error message this happens only after upgrading play services

Answer (score 5):

[image]If you want to use firebase or other google cloud platform then download google-services.json from link - https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/raafta-aac07/settings/general/

Else you don't want to use it then , just remove
`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`
from build.gradle from Android Studio

Answer (score 2):

That Problem is because:-
The folder or file you pasted to your product downloaded from the firebase console is not named as google-services.json.
so now click it then right mouse click in all the options open refractor and rename it to google-services.json. because this worked for me

Comment: as for me, I've pasted nothing, AS made all from Assistant... and what I should to rename now?

Comment: For some reason when I cloned the repo, the file was named mock-google-services.json. I renamed it and placed in app folder and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to firebase console
2. Create a new project.
3. Then go and click on Add Firebase to your Android app
4. Add Package name (from AndroidManifest.xml)
5. Then it'll generate google-services.json
6. Copy this file and add it to  (i) your project root (ii) your project>app
7. Sync project  (Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files)

Hope this will help to you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to the Firebase of the project, for example, you downloaded an example source code then you have to remove any Firebase related stuff to make the project run.

Search keywords in the project

- fabric
- firebase
- google-services
- crashlytics