# Flutter google-services.json file is missing error

Tags: flutter, firebase, gradle

I have placed the google-services.json file in the following path

[image]

Yet I get the error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
   Searched Location: 
  F:\downloads\food_delivery_app-master\food_delivery_app-master\android\app\src\debug\google-services.json
  F:\downloads\food_delivery_app-master\food_delivery_app-master\android\app\src\google-services.json
  F:\downloads\food_delivery_app-master\food_delivery_app-master\android\app\google-services.json


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 25s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I searched all solutions posted. But none worked. How do I resolve this? Please help have been struck for a while. Thank You.

Comment: try with `flutter clean` , also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33342306/10157127)

Comment: Is it me, or is there an extra whitespace in the filename? It's `google-services .json`, but should be `google-services.json`.

Comment: @DarjaOrlova I see it too. I checked in VS Code and this seems to be the case.

Comment: Can you show the place where you are initializing the Firebase? and also try by clearing the cache of the IDE  for android - Invalidate cache and Restart.

Comment: I have added `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` in the android/app level gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

### It seems like your Google Services file is incorrectly named!

If it is indeed incorrectly named, please rename it from:

`google-services .json`

to

`google-services.json`

There was an extra space!